# Setting up Coldfusion 9 on Windows Server 2012 with IIS8

Tags: windows-server-2012, coldfusion, iis-8

We've just upgraded our server to Windows 2012 which is running IIS8. I'm at a dead end trying to configure it to run Coldfusion 9 and serve the pages.

It installed fine with no errors but I cannot access the Admin panel (it gives me an 404.3 error).

Any advice would be appreciated as I am really struggling and haven't had much to so with servers post Windows 2003.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you run the web server configuration tool after the install?

Comment: The solution links are broken.
Can some provide alternative links to a solution?

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure Adobe will not be updating ColdFusion 9 to run on Windows 8/Server 2012/IIS8. Their most current release, CF10, also does not run under this platform but they are "working on it" with no release date announced yet. Recommendation is to switch to Railo for this platform.  I'm not sure if Open Blue Dragon also works under Windows Server 2012 but that could be another alternative.

Comment: This is a bit late; but the above answer is no longer complete.  Adobe has updated ColdFusion 10 to work on Windows Server 2012 [and Windows 8]: http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/new-platform-support-coldfusion-10.html .  I believe it came with a service pack, but I don't see a date.

Answer (score 1):

Are the features required enabled in your IIS settings (for ISAPI Extensions and ISAPI Filters)?  The ASP.NET feature *may* be required as well.  I think it is turned on by default.  Here is a link to a site with a video showing the installation process along with the settings needed.  NOTE: you do not need to enable the IIS Metabase 6 Compatibility mode option if you are installing 9.0.1 or later.

[ColdFusion 9 on Windows server 2008 64bit - with video](http://blog.kukiel.net/2009/10/coldfusion-9-on-windows-server-2008.html)

[Installing ColdFusion on IIS 7 + Configure IIS for ColdFusion in Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008](http://www.codecurry.com/2009/09/installing-coldfusion-on-iis-7.html)

*I realize the link I provided references Windows Server 2008 but I think it still relates to Windows Server 2012*

*And just to be clear - this configuration is NOT supported by Adobe*

**EDIT - Adding references on how to manually configure IIS**

http://www.codecurry.com/2010/01/coldfusion-manual-configuration-issues.html

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/iis-configuration.html

Comment: Thank you for the links, I will try these today to see if I have any luck with it!

Comment: Hi I have done the above and am still having the same issues! Any other ideas? 

Might have to try and set up a different server like Ben suggests above.

Comment: Are you still getting the 404.3 error?  Everything I found on that pointed to enabling the ISAPI options.  If you had to that on yours you would need to run the web server configuration tool again after doing so.  Are ColdFusion pages being processed?  If you put a simple `index.cfm` page in your web root does it get processed?

Comment: Hi I just tried re running the web server configuration tool and I am getting the error when I submit:

Warning, version 8.0 is installed supported versions are 4.x, 5.x, 6.x, 7.x.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried running the web server configuration tool in Windows 7 Compatibility Mode?  I found a couple of articles where that worked for people.  You could also attempt to configure the websites manually.  [Here is an article that explains that process.](http://www.codecurry.com/2010/01/coldfusion-manual-configuration-issues.html)  There are more examples of that if you do some searching.

Comment: The web server config tool will not open in any of the Compatibility Modes.

Will try the link you sent, thanks.

Comment: I will add some more links to the answer regarding how to configure IIS manually.  Even Adobe has a document about it.

Comment: Hi, four days on and now we are getting an asp.net error - HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error

Handler "AboMapperCustom-1304376500" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list.

It has been installed + added to the server roles.

This is a nightmare!

Comment: Link to new question http://serverfault.com/questions/473075/asp-net-4-5-and-windows-server-2012

Answer (score 1):

This link is the most promising one so far that I will try later and probably post back here on my results, not sure if there'd be a difference for CF9 but for your information:

http://www.andyscott.id.au/blog/installing-coldfusion-10-on-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012

---

Update ok I just tried this and it worked, took me 4 tries my mistake was that I replaced the **msvcrt.dll** in the Windows folder the first few times, when you ONLY replace the **resources** folder that has the JREs and what not, note this is on Windows 8 64-bit - then I ran the installer in **compatibility mode for Windows 7** and as an administrator

Another gotcha, you're probably wondering from that article where do I find another working program that uses InstallAnywhere? Well funnily InstallAnywhere installs itself with InstallAnywhere, so get the trial version and follow the steps - you are grabbing the unpacked install files in the AppData/"your name"/Local/Temp/i777777777 (random number here) folder that corresponds to your install

More in depth info: http://thefusionator.com/index.cfm?blogID=2